# Difference between NSLayoutAttributeWidth and NSLayoutAttributeLeft + NSLayoutAttributeRight

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

If I have 2 views view1 and view2. Assume that view1 has had its width set elsewhere. I want to make view2 the same width as view1

I can create a `LayoutConstraint` of `NSLayoutAttributeWidth` for view2 relating it to view1 and that should make the width of view2 the same as view1's width.

Alternatively I could create two `LayoutConstraints` for view2. One of `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` related to view1's Left and a second of `NSLayoutAttributeRight` related to view1's right. With their left and right edges the same doesn't that also make view2 the same as view1's width?

Are these equally valid approaches for matching widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is somehow "YES", depends on what are your requirements.

Keep in mind that with constraints

```
NSLayoutAttributeLeft 
NSLayoutAttributeRight
```

In case of horizontal relocation of your `view1`, `view2` will be relocated too, still keeping the same width.

In case of constraint

```
NSLayoutAttributeWidth
```

The horizontal relocation of the first `view1` will not cause the relocation of `view2`.

Comment: I have switched acceptance to this answer simply because of the extra info around the benefit of Left and Right wrt relocation